# Adds an empty directory in the archive

Tags: php

i want to Adds an empty directory in the archive.

```
ZipArchive::addEmptyDir
```

this function add it
but i the root only

assume i want add it in

```
/dir/dir/
```

i cant

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    if($zip->addEmptyDir('newDirectory')) {
        echo 'Created a new root directory';
    } else {
        echo 'Could not create the directory';
    }
    $zip->close();
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

this add it in the root
how i can add the new dir in sub dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Function to recursively add a directory,
// sub-directories and files to a zip archive
function addFolderToZip($dir, $zipArchive, $zipdir = ''){
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {

        //Add the directory
        $zipArchive->addEmptyDir($dir);

        // Loop through all the files
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

            //If it's a folder, run the function again!
            if(!is_file($dir . $file)){
                // Skip parent and root directories
                if( ($file !== ".") && ($file !== "..")){
                    addFolderToZip($dir . $file . "/", $zipArchive, $zipdir . $file . "/");
                }

            }else{
                // Add the files
                $zipArchive->addFile($dir . $file, $zipdir . $file);

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Source: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addemptydir.php)