# Why does my zip code not work as expected?

Tags: php, file, zip

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190540/adds-an-empty-directory-in-the-archive). I can't use that code:

```
function addFolderToZip($dir, $zipArchive, $zipdir = ''){
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {

        //Add the directory
        $zipArchive->addEmptyDir($dir);

        // Loop through all the files
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

            //If it's a folder, run the function again!
            if(!is_file($dir . $file)){
                // Skip parent and root directories
                if( ($file !== ".") && ($file !== "..")){
                    addFolderToZip($dir . $file . "/", $zipArchive, $zipdir . $file . "/");
                }

            }else{
                // Add the files
                $zipArchive->addFile($dir . $file, $zipdir . $file);

            }
        }
    }
```

Please write an example for me. The second problem is too complex.

When I use `addfile` function it will add and appear in the archive as a file and this great. Now when I use:

```
$z = new ZipArchive();
$z->open('test.zip')

for ($i=0; $i< $z->numFiles;$i++) {
 $aZipDtls = $z->statIndex($i);

echo $aZipDtls['name'];
}
```

it now shows if I add a file in folder like that:

```
    $zip->addFile('/path/to/index.txt', 'dir/newname.txt');
```

it show in the Winrar soft a dir then a file but in the code it shows it as one file.

Like that in winrar:

```
dir/

dir/newname.txt
```

In my PHP system, just only show one file without its dir, like that:

```
dir/newname.txt
```

This mean it's impossible to add a new file in a dir.

Comment: please explain what you want us to write example for you.

Comment: Your problem is not clear to me, and you don't use punctuation or capitals, which makes your question hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to know what you want, but here goes:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('test.zip');
$zip->addFile('/path/to/newname.txt','dir/newname1.txt');
$zip->addFile('/path/to/newname.txt','dir/newname2.txt');
$zip->addFile('/path/to/newname.txt','dir/dir/newname3.txt');
$zip->addFile('/path/to/newname.txt','dir/dir/dir/newname4.txt');

for ($i=0; $i< $zip->numFiles;++$i) {
    $aZipDtls = $zip->statIndex($i);
    echo $aZipDtls['name'],"\n";
}

$zip->close();
?>
```

Should cover all questions. That will unzip with exactly the structure you'd expect it to. The discrepancy is likely due to the way WinRar displays the archive structure.

Comment: I wonder why this wasn't accepted or even commented on, by @moustafa